# Which is better in Laravel - use Input::get() in Controller or Model?

Tags: laravel

I wanted to ask, looking from the 'best practices' side, which solution is better, getting a form data in Controller and passing it to Model, or retrieving it directly in the Model?

I use the first solution, which makes your controller methods very long and ugly, but I think it is still the right choice. But recently I have seen some other projects source code where the form data is retrieved in model, but it seems that it breaks the rule, where the model should not know, where the data comes from.

So which is the better practice?

Comment: Definitely in the controller! Add the controller code to your question, maybe it can be optimized / shortened somehow...

Comment: I have exactly two problems:

 1) I have too much fields in my form, so assigning each one to pass it later to a model makes the controller bigger
 2) I often have to add images which makes logic of creating folders forthose images depending on which user has created it or the number of the topic too complicated and that is a lot of lines of code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lukasgeiter said in the Comments, I also say this would typically be done in the controller.

You may want to have a look at the corresponding laracasts on

1. [MVC](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/2)
2. [Models](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/3)
3. [Controllers](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/8)

Basically, you already said it. Models are just kind of "storage-interfaces" while Controllers are places, where the logic happens.

Also, have a look at [MassAssigment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment), which cannot be done within the Model itsself but in the controller. This might be of interest in your case (without knowing the details).